# Is it possible to speed up image transfer from jpeg color camera (connected to arduino mega) to my computer via serial ports?

Tags: performance, camera, arduino, serial-port

What I'm using:

1) LinkSprite JPEG Color Camera TTL Interface - Infrared

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11610

2) Arduino Mega

I have this color camera connected to my arduino and I was able to print the hex values of the picture the camera takes on the serial monitor. The problem is it takes approximately 30 seconds for the camera to finish with one picture. My end goal is to do some image processing from the images I get from the arduino-camera setup, which I'll have attached to a toy car. Of course at that point, I'll have to send the images wirelessly (XBees or wifi?).

My question is: Is the setup I have supposed to be this slow or am I missing something? I've read in numerous places that microcontrollers like the arduino are not suited for this task because they have low processing power. Also, I recall someone blaming the transfer rate via serial ports being slow. Should I abandon the setup I have for a different solution?

Edit: Do I need a camera shield?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

/* Linksprite */
byte incomingbyte;
SoftwareSerial mySerial(5, 4); // RX, TX         //Configure pin 4 and 5 as soft serial port

int a=0x0000,j=0,k=0,count=0;                    //Read Starting address       
uint8_t MH,ML;
boolean EndFlag=0;

void SendResetCmd();
void SendTakePhotoCmd();
void SendReadDataCmd();
void StopTakePhotoCmd();

void setup()
{ 
  Serial.begin(19200);
  mySerial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() 
{
     SendResetCmd();
     delay(4000);                               //After reset, wait 2-3 second to send take picture command

      SendTakePhotoCmd();

     while(mySerial.available()>0)
      {
        incomingbyte=mySerial.read();

      }   
      byte a[32];

      while(!EndFlag)
      {  
         j=0;
         k=0;
         count=0;
         SendReadDataCmd();

         delay(25);
          while(mySerial.available()>0)
          {
               incomingbyte=mySerial.read();
               k++;
               if((k>5)&&(j<32)&&(!EndFlag))
               {
               a[j]=incomingbyte;
               if((a[j-1]==0xFF)&&(a[j]==0xD9))      //Check if the picture is over
               EndFlag=1;                           
               j++;
           count++;
               }
          }

          for(j=0;j<count;j++)
          {   if(a[j]<0x10)
              Serial.print("0");
              Serial.print(a[j],HEX);
              Serial.print(" ");
          }                                       //Send jpeg picture over the serial port
          Serial.println();
      }      
     while(1);
}

//Send Reset command
void SendResetCmd()
{
      mySerial.write(0x56);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write(0x26);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
}

//Send take picture command
void SendTakePhotoCmd()
{
      mySerial.write(0x56);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write(0x36);
      mySerial.write(0x01);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);  
}

//Read data
void SendReadDataCmd()
{
      MH=a/0x100;
      ML=a%0x100;
      mySerial.write(0x56);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write(0x32);
      mySerial.write(0x0c);
      mySerial.write((byte)0); 
      mySerial.write(0x0a);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write(MH);
      mySerial.write(ML);   
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write(0x20);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);  
      mySerial.write(0x0a);
      a+=0x20;                            //address increases 32£¬set according to buffer size
}

void StopTakePhotoCmd()
{
      mySerial.write(0x56);
      mySerial.write((byte)0);
      mySerial.write(0x36);
      mySerial.write(0x01);
      mySerial.write(0x03);        
}
```

Comment: This is strange. Usually images are big, but your camera module gives you a jpeg (so a compressed file) and has a low resolution, so it should go faster. Please post your code. Since the module is serial, any serial interface module (xbee, bluetooth, wifi, other modules) is ok, since you just have to forward the bytes read on another interface. Just use an hardware serial instead of a software one, then try to 1) increase the camera baud rate, 2) lower the resolution, 3) change the compression ratio. And.. a shield is just for connections. If you already connected the camera you don't need one

Comment: Thank you for your input! It led me to something I can experiment and work with.

Comment: I tried hardware serial like you suggested, but it was taking just as long. I posted a followup question about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100518/why-am-i-getting-the-same-performance-from-hardware-serial-and-software-serial