# Why am I getting the same performance from Hardware Serial and Software Serial?

Tags: performance, camera, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to interface (1) LinkSprite JPEG Color Camera TTL Interface - Infrared and (2) Arduino Mega 2560 connected to my laptop. While I am able to print the HEX values of the images, it takes about 30 seconds to print 1 image to the monitor. I thought that it was because I was using SoftwareSerial, so I tried HardwareSerial, but still, 30 seconds per image. Shouldn't it be faster using HardwareSerial? Just wondering, do I need a special cable connecting the arduino to my laptop?

I tried different combinations of baud rates for Serial and Serial1. (Serial.begin(9600), Serial1.begin(38400)), (Serial.begin(38400), Serial1.begin(38400)) etc... This doesn't work when I set Serial1 anything higher than 38400. (It should be able to go higher..) Also, do I have to increase baud rate by a certain interval namely, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 74880, 115200, 230400, 250000?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 

byte incomingbyte;

//Configure pin 2 and 3 as soft serial port
//SoftwareSerial Serial1 = SoftwareSerial(2, 3); 

int a=0x0000,  //Read Starting address     
    j=0,
    k=0,
    count=0;
uint8_t MH,ML;
boolean EndFlag=0;


void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(38400); //made changes in ChangeBaudRate()
  ChangeBaudRate();[enter image description here][1]
  SendResetCmd();
  delay(3000);
}

void loop() {
  SendTakePhotoCmd();

  Serial.println("Start pic"); 
  delay(100);

  while(Serial1.available()>0) {
    incomingbyte=Serial1.read();
  }
  byte b[32];

  while(!EndFlag) {  
    j=0;
    k=0;
    count=0;
    SendReadDataCmd();

    delay(75); //try going up
    while(Serial1.available()>0) {
      incomingbyte=Serial1.read();
      k++;
      if((k>5)&&(j<32)&&(!EndFlag)) {
        b[j]=incomingbyte;
        if((b[j-1]==0xFF)&&(b[j]==0xD9))
        EndFlag=1;                           
        j++;
        count++;
      }
    }

    for(j=0;j<count;j++) {   
      if(b[j]<0x10)
        Serial.print("0");
      Serial.print(b[j], HEX);
    }
    Serial.println();
  }

  delay(3000);
  StopTakePhotoCmd(); //stop this picture so another one can be taken
  EndFlag = 0; //reset flag to allow another picture to be read
  Serial.println("End of pic");
  Serial.println(); 
  while(1);
}

//Send Reset command
void SendResetCmd() {
  Serial1.write((byte)0x56);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x26);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);   
}

//Send take picture command
void SendTakePhotoCmd() {
  Serial1.write((byte)0x56);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x36);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x01);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);

  a = 0x0000; //reset so that another picture can taken
}

void FrameSize() {
  Serial1.write((byte)0x56);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x34);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x01);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);  
}

//Read data
void SendReadDataCmd() {
  MH=a/0x100;
  ML=a%0x100;

  Serial1.write((byte)0x56);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x32);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x0c);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x0a);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)MH);
  Serial1.write((byte)ML);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x20);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x0a);

  a+=0x20; 
}

void StopTakePhotoCmd() {
  Serial1.write((byte)0x56);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x36);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x01);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x03);        
}

void ChangeBaudRate(){
  Serial1.write((byte)0x56);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x24);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x03);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x01);   
  Serial1.write((byte)0x0D); // 115200 = 0x0D 0xA6
  Serial1.write((byte)0xA6);

  Serial1.end(); // Not really necessary
  Serial1.begin( 115200 ); // change to match the camera's new baud rate
}
```

Comment: I guess the baud rate is the significant part to determine the performance than use whether SoftwareSerial or HardwareSerial.

Comment: That's a good point. Regarding that, I tried increasing the baud rate on both Serial and Serial1, but when I do that, I don't get the HEX values (I just end up printing new empty lines). The code in while(Serial1.available()>0) doesn't get executed. I'm not sure why it doesn't work when I increase the baud rate...

Comment: @use1270075 Are you sure you updated the baud rate setting of whom the Arduino will communicate with?

Comment: Do you mean Serial1.begin( increased baud rate here) in the setup()?

Comment: Oh do I have to send commands to the camera to change the camera  baud rate?

Comment: Yes, I mwan `Serial1.begin( increased baud rate here)` and I don't know about the camera, so check your documents.

Comment: What do you mean by updating the baud rate? Is there something else I need to update the baud rate besides Serial1.begin( increased baud rate here)? I checked the documentations and they had a page where you they have commands to change baud rates. I tried that, but that didn't work either. Also what is the relationship between Serial baud rate and Serial1 baud rate? What should I set them to relative to each other? From experimentation, I believe Serial baud rate has to be less than or equal to Serial1 baud rate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the baud rate between the Arduino and the camera is the determining factor.   The baud rate between the Arduino and the PC (i.e., the Serial Monitor window) is 9600, but you can change that to 115200 in the code with `Serial.begin(115200);` and in the Serial Monitor window (pulldown in corner).

The default baud rate between the Arduino and the camera is 38400.  While at that baud rate, you can send the "Change Baud Rate" command (section 9 on page 6/10 of the [spec](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Imaging/1274419957.pdf)).  That seems to be the purpose of this routine:

```
void ChangeBaudRate(){
  Serial1.write((byte)0x56);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x24);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x03);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x01);   
  Serial1.write((byte)0x1c);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x4c);   
}
```

According to the spec, this sets the new baud rate to 57600.  You could choose 115200 by changing the last two bytes to 0x0D and 0xA6.  **Then** you have to set `Serial1` to the new baud rate:

```
void ChangeBaudRate(){
  Serial1.write((byte)0x56);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x00);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x24);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x03);
  Serial1.write((byte)0x01);   
  Serial1.write((byte)0x0D); // 115200 = 0x0D 0xA6
  Serial1.write((byte)0xA6);

  Serial1.end(); // Not really necessary
  Serial1.begin( 115200 ); // change to match the camera's new baud rate
}
```

Comment: I updated the code as you have suggested. It makes more sense. So I'm running the code as it is above. (modified ChangedBaudRate()) In the Serial Monitor window, I set it to 115200 baud in the pulldown menu. When I do that, I only end up printing new lines. The while(Serial1.available()>0) is not being executed.

Comment: Now that you've changed the baud rate (yeah!), the `delay` statements don't quite work the way they used to... the timing is different.  I recommend taking a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/linksprite-serial-cam-arduino/source/browse).  The `readData` method shows a better way to skip the 5-byte response and watch for the FF D9 end marker (`flag` is a state variable).  It's not quite right, but it's better that what you're starting with.  :(  For example, most `delay`s are gone, but it waits until 1 character is available, then reads 5 without checking.  You have to read the response.

Comment: After a little googling, I can't find a better library.  Like I said, it may have a few reliability problems, but it's a better starting point.  The sketch you posted does a bad thing on the first byte of the response:  `j` would be zero, and it would test `b[j-1]`, which is `b[-1]`.  xP  Although you didn't ask, `HardwareSerial` is the only way to go, especially at 115200.

Comment: ...and I see this code is a derivative of LinkSprite's example.  *Bad* example, that is...  How can the  manufacturer's code be that bad?  :(  Well, like I said, the JPEGlibrary is a better starting point.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I'm going to comb through what you said and maybe I'll get something to work. :) but man, who knew it'd be this confusing to change a baud rate?

Comment: Yep, the same thing happens when you change the baud rate of a GPS device.  First, you send a special command, *then* you have to change your own baud rate.  Hopefully, the GPS received the command ok.  Kinda like changing frequencies on a pair of walkie-talkies.  :)